# Fragments not showing in Navigation Drawer clicks

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

i am very new to Android Developing, have been developing mainly for ios for several years now but having problems in my first android app.

I am developing an app where at the beginning you have log in, so i created the UI and the login button and so far that works great, the app is able to connect to the database a download the necessary information for it to work via xml.

The downloaded Xml gives the items in the navigation drawer their names,
Basically all of the navigation drawer items should lead you to the same fragment, the content changes when loading the contents of the downloaded xml to it, but the window remains the same.

So in order to do this i created the navigation drawer items programmatically, added the ui for the fragment in a new xml.

When running the app everything works great, once you are logged in you are able to open the NavigationDrawer by swiping right, the right Items and names appear, but when clicking an item... nothing happens.
I used `LOGE` to know if the code was working and witch menu item was trying to open and it does return always the right menu item etc.

If there is a code in the fragment it executes the code and returns what its expected, but its simply not visible.

Here is my onNavigationItemSelected in MainActivity.

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    String title = item.getTitle().toString();
    int order = (int) getMenuItemTag(item);
    if (title != "Modos Personales" && title != "Home") {
        Log.e("onNavigationItem: ", Integer.toString(order));

        Fragment fragment = null;

        Class fragmentClass;

        fragmentClass = MainFragment.class;

        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.flContent, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        //android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        //fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();

    }
```

Here is the XML of my main activity "activity_main.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/flContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.paranoidinteractive.heimer.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:foreground="@mipmap/logo_menu"
    android:foregroundGravity="center">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is the XML of my Fragment "room_view.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/room_view"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorScreen"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my fragmet "MainFragment.java"

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        int number = 0;

        if (inflater != null){
            Log.e("INFLATER NO NULL: ", Integer.toString(number));
        } else {
            Log.e("INFLATER NULL: ", Integer.toString(number));
        }

        if (container != null){
            Log.e("CONTAINTER NO NULL: ", Integer.toString(number));
        } else {
            Log.e("CONTAINER NULL: ", Integer.toString(number));
        }
    


        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.room_view, container, false);
    }
}
```

And if you view the LOGCAT it allways returns:

> 01-26 16:27:36.771 9259-9259/com.paranoidinteractive.heimer E/INFLATER NO NULL:: 0
>
> 01-26 16:27:36.771 9259-9259/com.paranoidinteractive.heimer E/CONTAINER NO NULL:: 0

So i know its working and getting there but its simply not showing it.

I've followed all the tutorials available and read tons of questions and answers here but none of the answers have helped me so far so i Decided to post this question.

Thank you in advance for your help, hope you can assist me with this.
Sorry for the log post!

Comment: don't you want to replace the current Fragment displayed? `fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.flContent, fragment);`. Just noticed you actually have that code commented out a few lines lower. Did that also not work?

Comment: Yes, have tried it, and just in case i just tried again changing '.add' to '.replace' but the exact same thing happens.
Will update my question to include "activity_main.xml", but i thing the main problem is exactly what you said, im trying to replace the fragment.... but in truth (at least not in my code) there is no fragment displayed at the time so there is nothing to be replaced... tho in the tutotials the code is just like mine! so i have no idea.

Comment: Just out of curiosity why are you expecting anything different to be shown since you are always setting the Fragment to the same one? `fragmentClass = MainFragment.class;`. Is a different fragment shown by default?

Comment: yes, it should be that same fragment always, the content inside the fragment will change depending on what item you clicked and the content already downloaded and parsed from the xml, (except when clicking "Home" it shoud take you to another fragment, but that is specified in the code) right now home has no fragment, will do it later.

Thats the thing, basicaly my main window is not a fragment its all programmed in main activity and the layout is the 'content_main.xml' ... so in the beginning i am actually in no fragment! what i want is that when the item is clicked to show a new fragment.

Comment: You'll need to show your MainActivity layout file. What kind of container is `R.id.flContent` and what do you put in it by default then when the application starts?

Comment: Added it to my question.
Basically it has nothing, as in the tutorial, it says you should add a placeholder to be able to call it so, flContent is the placeholder (because the main one is another xml)